Simple parametrization of biholomorphism from a simple ellipse to the unit disk.
Let $D  = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mbox{ with } |z|<1 \}$ be the open unit complex disk.
Let $E_r= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mbox{ with } (\frac{\Re{z}}{r})^2 + (\Im{z})^2 < 1 \} $ be an open axis-aligned ellipse in the complex plane, centered at the origin, of major axis $r>0$.
Question: Is there a simple parametrization of the set of all biholomorphism $E_r \to D$ (i.e. bijective conformal maps) ?
Note: Since both $D$ and $E_r$ are non-empty simply connected open domain, the Riemann mapping theorem tells us that

such biholomorphism do exists for all $r>0$
for any $\alpha \in D$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ there is an unique biholomorphism $f : E_r \to D$ with $f(0)=\alpha$ and $\arg(f'(0))=\theta$

Of course for $r=1$ we have $E_1 = D$ and the biholomorphism  $f$ is an automorphisme of the unit disk whose parametrization is well known as $f(z)=\rho \frac{z-\alpha}{z \bar{\alpha} - 1}$ for some $|\rho|=1$ and $\alpha \in D$. My question is thus, what happens when the source domain (equiv. image) is deformed from a disk to an ellipse ?
